# Correct user configuration for aws-cli container

Tags: docker, aws-cli, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-volume, pengwin

The AWS CLI v2 documentation presents an option and guide to [installing / configuring the cli via docker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-docker.html). The guide is straightforward enough to follow, and the container works fine with the key items being

- mounting the local `.aws` directory to provide credentials to the container
- mounting `$pwd` for any I/O work required

I'm using it for s3 and realized that any files I copy to my local drive from s3 show as owned by `root`.

```
>docker run --rm -v "$HOME/.aws:/root/.aws:rw" -v "$PWD:/aws:rw" amazon/aws-cli s3 cp s3://xxx/hello .
download: s3://xxx/hello to ./hello
>ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct  2 09:43 hello
```

This makes sense, as the process is running as `root` in the container, but isn't ideal. There isn't a any other user in the container, so I can't just run "as" `kirk`.

```
>docker run --rm -u kirk -v "$HOME/.aws:/root/.aws:rw" -v "$PWD:/aws:rw" amazon/aws-cli s3 cp s3://xxx/hello .
docker: Error response from daemon: unable to find user kirk: no matching entries in passwd file.
```

Is there a way to mount the volume "as" a user or by delegating user access to the container? I don't care (& not sure I can control) the user inside the container, but I would like the process to run in the context of a user on the host system. What's the right approach here?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a container as a user that doesn't exist inside the image using numerical values for `-u ${UID}:${GID}`. For example:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u 1000:1000 \
    -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} \
    -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} \
    -v ${PWD}:/aws:rw \
    amazon/aws-cli s3 cp s3://devops-example/lolz.gif .
```

... will copy the file as `UID` 1000 `GID` 1000.

> **Note**: using `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables for passing credentials instead of mounting the credentials file. The full list of environment variables is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html).

[image: AWS CLI copy as UID:GID 1000]